# displaying top 5 items

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system, view

I'm creating my website found [here](http://www.xclo.mobi/xclo2)

and am creating a page called [more](http://www.xclo.mobi/xclo2/more.php).

Within this page I want to add a list of my top 5 promotions on my site. Each promotion is saved in my mobi database in mysql and I have added a count for each time someone views a particular promotion on my single.php page.

So basically. What I need to do is display 5 promotions with the highest number in the "views" field in my mobi database.

I currently have these codes:

```
include_once('include/connection.php');
include_once('include/article.php');
```

and

```
<?php foreach ($articles as $article) { ?>

<a href="list.php?id=<?php echo $article['promo_title']; ?>">
<?php echo $article['promo_title']; ?>
</a>
```

in more.php and also

```
class views {
public function fetch_all(){
   global $pdo;

 $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM mobi ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 0, 5");
   $query->execute();

return $query->fetch(); 

}

}
```

in articles.php **which only loads some weird text of "t t t t h h w w d d d d 3 3"**

what more will I need to add to get this to work?

thank you.

Comment: I'll give you a clue: `fetch`

Comment: re read my post. it just loads a blank page.

Comment: Check out the "selecting data" section of http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Comment: Return its not needed.

Comment: And they call me crazy. Well, they're partially right. *I'm no dog, but I can "fetch"* ;-)

Comment: ok. I've made my post a lot more clear. Please advise now. thanks.